# Implement BFS to return path of minimal length from vertex s to t

Tags: c, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am trying to implement Breadth First Search where four functions: `int move1(int)`, `int move2(int)`, `int move3(int)`, `int move4(int)` each generates a new vertex from a given vertex, or returns -1 if that move is not possible. I have to write the function:

`struct listnode * bfspath(int s, int t)`

where `struct listnode { int v, struct listnode *next };`

The function should return a list of vertices that starts at vertex s and ends at vertex t, and is a path of minimal length from `s` to `t`. If no path exists, it returns NULL.

To store all currently reached vertices, I use a height-balanced tree. The queue should be a linked list. In the search tree, I need to store with each known state also the state from which it was reached. Storing the move is not necessary since it can be reconstructed by trying the three possible moves. With that information, the path can be reconstructed from the starting state to the target state, in reverse sequence.

I know I shouldn't be asking for help without trial/error, but I am really stumped. I am not sure how to approach this and how to begin. If anyone can give me a headstart or give me an explanation of what to do, it be greatly appreciated. I know this isn't an intellectual question worth diving into and isn't worth being asked on stackoverflow but I would really appreciate any help at all.

The four move functions are the following:

```
int move1(int i)
{  int x, y, z, newx, newy, newz;
   z = i/100000;
   x = i %1000;
   y = (i/1000)%100;
   {  newx = (x+1)%1000; newy = y; newz = z;}
   return(newz*100000 +newy*1000 + newx );
}

int move2(int i)
{  int x, y, z, newx, newy, newz;
   z = i/100000;
   x = i %1000;
   y = (i/1000)%100;
   {  newx = (x+999)%1000; newy = y; newz = z;}
   return(newz*100000 +newy*1000 + newx );
}

int move3(int i)
{  int x, y, z, newx, newy, newz;
   z = i/100000;
   x = i %1000;
   y = (i/1000)%100;
   if( (x!=0) || (y!=0))
   {  newx = x; newy = (y+1)%100; newz = z;}
   else /* (x==0) && (y==0))*/
   {newx = x; newy = y; newz = (z + 1)%4;} 
   return(newz*100000 +newy*1000 + newx );
}

int move4(int i)
{  int x, y, z, newx, newy, newz;
   z = i/100000;
   x = i %1000;
   y = (i/1000)%100;
   if( (x!=0) || (y!=0))
   {  newx = x; newy = (y+99)%100; newz = z;}
   else /* ((x==0) && (y=0)) */
   {newx = x; newy = y; newz = (z+3)%4;} 
   return(newz*100000 +newy*1000 + newx );
}
```

The test code:

```
int main()
{  int i, j, k;
    struct listnode * path;
   for( k=0; k<10; k++ )  
   {  i = rand()%400000; j = rand()%400000;
      printf("Test %d: from %d to %d:", k, i, j);
      path = bfspath(i,j);
      if(path == NULL)
      { printf("Failed: no path found.\n"); fflush(stdout); exit(0);}
      if( path->v != i)
      {  printf("Failed.\n wrong startvertex. Should go from %d to %d; starts at %d\n",
        i,j, path->v); fflush(stdout); exit(0);
      }
      else
      {  while( path->v != j && path->next != NULL)
    {  if( path->next->v == move1(path->v)
              || path->next->v == move2(path->v)
              || path->next->v == move3(path->v)
           || path->next->v == move4(path->v) )
          path = path-> next;
       else
       {  printf("Failed.\n wrong next vertex on path: %d is not neighbor of %d\n",
            path->next->v, path->v );
          fflush(stdout); exit(0);
           } 
        }
        if( path->v != j )         
    {  printf("Failed.\n wrong final vertex; should be %d, is %d\n", j, path->v);
       fflush(stdout); exit(0);
        }
      }
      printf("Passed.\n");
   }
   printf("Tested 10 random paths\n");
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Do you understand how BFS works? If not, read up on it. If you do, what part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have an auxiliary structure, maybe an array can do the trick, such that you store the "parent" of each node. Think about the BFS traversal as a way to generate a rooted spanning tree. In terms of BFS, each time you add u, a non-visited neighbor of vertex v into the queue, you signal that v is the parent of u, that is that you needed to find v in order to find u. Then to build the path is just "backtracking" on this tree once you found your destination vertex. I mean that you may look at the "parent" of your destination vertex and then you get the parent of the parent until you get to the root, that is the source vertex.

If your edges have weights, then you can also modify Dijkstra's to do the same thing.

Finding the path before finding the destination is very cumbersome, since there are a lots of possibles paths that you have to keep track of, since you don't know beforehand from which path the destiny will show up. Using the parent reference is an implicit way to store all shortest paths from the source to all vertices, without growing the complexity of BFS. You do not build all paths, but this way you are able to retrieve any desired path starting at the source vertex.

You can also build the whole BFS tree, and then find the path from the destiny to the root, in some sense it is the same, but maybe more intuitive way.